# What is this asking for?

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory

Now let B(n) be the time it takes to sort n elements for  bubbleSort. Let Q(n) be the time it takes for quickSort to sort n elements. Let M(n) be the time it takes for mergeSort. to sort n elements . In a Word document or in a text file, create a table of the following data which your program(s) will produce using the functions you developed in 1) 2) 3) and 4).

```
n      B(n)   B(n)/n^2 ......... etc i just need to know what this is asking for
1000                        
2000                        
4000                        
8000                        
16000
```

one question what is B(n) asking for in this ? I already finish coding and it shows me number of comparison and number of swaps. Do i need a stop watch to time it or something?!?!

I just dont get what it is asking for

Comment: From your question, B(n) is the time it takes to sort n elements using bubble sort which is O(n^2). But I don't understand the second part of your question, please provide more detail.

Comment: it it is like a chart it want me to fill in B(n) and then B(n)/n^2 
so what do i put in for B(n)??  i know n^2 for the first one is 1000^2

Comment: You need to look up the running time of each of those sorting methods... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: oh i figure it out that crazy  teacher actually want us to FIND the RUNNING time on my computer. Ty for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand the question asks you to state how many operations would the algorithms need to perform for each of the input sets.

For example, if insertion sort is O(n^2), you'd have

```
 n     O(n^2)    ...
1000  1000000
2000  2000000
4000  4000000
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a stopwatch, using time related functions.

However, from my experience, such homework assignments usually ask for number of comparisons and not actual time. Actual time will vary from Environment to Environment.

Comment: i got it ty for help! need to use 
 QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
to find time since quick and merge sort are too fast for s

Answer (score 0):

"using the functions you developed in 1) 2) 3) and 4)"

you must have very precise definitions of B(n) if you developed them in 1, 2, 3, 4 -- use those rather than those suggested here.  they should look like polynomials over n with integer coefficients and powers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a good grade:

Your homework mentions a program you have created, presumably that implements the algorithms you listed. Add some timing code that prints system ticks before and after performing a sort with 1000,2000,4000,8000,16000 items. Then subtract the difference, and put the time taken into your answer table.

Then do what the other guys say, and create a new answer table with the theoretical "Big O" answers.

Ideally you'd overlay both as a graph to highlight the difference between theory and your implementation.